# Spotify Web API - How To Extend Permissions Scope After Login?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, spotify

Is there any way to request extra (optional) permissions after the user is logged in, OR make some permissions optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OAuth, if you need to extend permissions scope, you just issue a new authorization request with the new scopes. The user will be asked again to consent to the new permissions and you will get a new access token, with the extended permissions.

It doesn't matter whether the user is logged in or not, or whether they already consented to give permissions to your app.